# How do I load python modules which are not available in Sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I want to install spacy which is not available as part of the Sagemaker platform. How should can I pip install it?

Comment: Issue resolved. I used !pip install

Comment: pip install is the way to add a python library to the notebook instance. If you want to reuse it also in the training jobs or the hosting options, you need to add it to the Docker images that are used there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When creating you model, you can specify the requirements.txt as an environment variable.

For Eg.

```
env = {
    'SAGEMAKER_REQUIREMENTS': 'requirements.txt', # path relative to `source_dir` below.
}
sagemaker_model = TensorFlowModel(model_data = 's3://mybucket/modelTarFile,
                                  role = role,
                                  entry_point = 'entry.py',
                                  code_location = 's3://mybucket/runtime-code/',
                                  source_dir = 'src',
                                  env = env,
                                  name = 'model_name',
                                  sagemaker_session = sagemaker_session,
                                 )
```

This would ensure that the requirements file is run after the docker container is created, before running any code on it.

Answer (score 5):

Great answer from Raman. I wanted to add another way of specifying the required python modules in the training instance, in case someone is looking.

```
tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='tf-train.py', role='SageMakerRole',
                          training_steps=10000, evaluation_steps=100,
                          train_instance_count=1,
                          source_dir='./',
                          requirements_file='requirements.txt',
                          train_instance_type='ml.p2.xlarge')
```

`source_dir` and `requirements_file` both have to be defined for it to work. 
The path is wrt to the notebook instance. If `requirements.txt` is under the same directory as the notebook, then just use './'

Docs is [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sagemaker.tensorflow.html#sagemaker.tensorflow.estimator.TensorFlow).