# Installing Pytorch Transformers in AWS Sagemaker

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to install the pytorch transformers package for my AWS Sagemaker notebook instance. However, it keeps giving me error of "No Module Found" for the package when i run my entry point script.

I saw in an example for TensorFlowModel which requires to set up env but for Pytorch it is not the case ([How do I load python modules which are not available in Sagemaker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665241/how-do-i-load-python-modules-which-are-not-available-in-sagemaker/49676109)). Anyway, below is my code :

```
estimator = PyTorch(entry_point='model.py',
                role=role,
                framework_version='1.4.0',
                train_instance_count=2,
                train_instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
                source_dir = 'src',
                hyperparameters={
                    'train_path': 's3://bucket-train',
                    'validation_path': 's3://bucket-val',
                    'epochs': 3,
                    'backend': 'gloo'
                })
```

Answer (score 1):

although you may be running that command from a SageMaker notebook, the training job you launch with the `PyTorch` estimator does not run on the notebook. It runs on remote, ephemeral infrastructure. You need to install your package on that remote machine. You need to add in the `src`source directory a `requirements.txt` file that contains the list of extra packages you want to install, such as the `transformers` package

Answer (score 0):

Olivier is correct, you can add the transformers package to the requirements.txt file prior to deploying the estimator. This [documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/using_pytorch.html#create-the-directory-structure-for-your-model-files) shows the appropriate directory structure you would need. More info on different PyTorch version requirements can be found [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/using_pytorch.html#using-third-party-libraries).