# While integrating sagemaker endpoint with datadog is there any way we dont use cloudwatch logs

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker, tensorflow-serving, datadog

I am trying to integrate SageMaker endpoint which uses inbuilt sagemaker container with datadog. So if i want to integrate it with datadog is there a way to not use cloudwatch and still get the logs or metrics. I found ddtrace can help with it but the issue is since using ddtrace requires to run gunicorn using ddtrace but for that i would need to build a container but that wont be possible since I am using inbuilt container. Is it possible to use ddtrace somehow? Majorly if I want to use tensorflow serving (AWS)container with datadog how can I use it without using cloudwatch logs

I have followed this tutorial but I want to know how can I use it with inbuilt containerhttps://medium.com/tech-shift-com/monitoring-amazon-sagemaker-endpointwith-datadog-ae40dd2fab05

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the prebuilt images. Follow the Sagemaker docs for [extending a prebuilt container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/prebuilt-containers-extend.html). In step 2, they demonstrate how to define the base image you are extending. Once you have that, I think it should be as easy as adding `RUN pip install ddtrace` to your dockerfile.

You might also try [adding a sagemaker requirements ENV var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665241/how-do-i-load-python-modules-which-are-not-available-in-sagemaker) when defining the model if that works for you.

Comment: actually it wont be possible to use ecr so we cant extend the container as well

Comment: then you've answered your own question, you can't do what you're trying to do with those limitations